# How to Omit Missing Fields from Date String (day, month, year)?

Tags: swift, date

I have a `DateFormatter` where `dateStyle` is set to `.long` like so:

```swift
private let formatter: DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateStyle = .long

  return formatter
}()
```

In my application, I make requests to an API and can receive some info about dates in the response body. In response, it'll look like this for example:

```swift
struct StartDate {
  let day: Int?
  let month: Int?
  let year: Int?
}
```

As all the fields are optional, some fields may or may not be present. For example, I may have a year and month, but not a day. Or maybe I only have the year. A demonstration of why this is a problem:

```swift
let date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 12))!

print(formatter.string(from: date))
```

We have the year and month, but not the day. I may expect it to look like `December 2020`, `December, 2020` or even `December ?, 2020`. However, it decides to replace the missing day with a 1. I can't use that because it's misleading to the user. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: If day is nil, set it to 1 or any number smaller than 29?

Comment: If `day` is `nil`, I'd like to not replace it with some other number. Like if `day` is `nil`, `month` is 12, and `year` is 2020, I'd be fine with `December 2020`, `December, 2020` or `December ?, 2020`. However, I'm not fine with `December 1, 2020` (what it currently does) because it's misleading to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bit straight-forward but still. You can try something like this:

```swift
struct StartDate {
    let day: Int?
    let month: Int?
    let year: Int?
    
    var string: String {
        get {
            let daySymbols = day == nil ? "??" : String(day!)
            let monthSymbols = month == nil ? "??" : DateFormatter().monthSymbols[month! - 1]
            let yearSymbols = year == nil ? "??" : String(year!)
            return "\(daySymbols) \(monthSymbols) \(yearSymbols)"
        }
    }

}

print(StartDate(day: nil, month: 10, year: 2020).string)
//prints '?? October 2020'
print(StartDate(day: 21, month: nil, year: 2020).string)
//prints '21 ?? 2020'
print(StartDate(day: 21, month: 9, year: nil).string)
//prints '21 September ??'
```